# CSS visited links code. Link who is opened to stay in other color. Where is my mistake?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

When someone open a link in my menu i want the style of the link to change with the same style as the hover and stay in this till the user is on that page.

I make mistake somewhere and i cant find where. I hope someone can help me. I know there is a lot of other similar questions but i know the way how to do it but i do some mistake in my code and cant find it.

**EDIT:**

*I found where is my mistake so i will edit the code with the correct one if anyone needs this in the feature.*

HTML CODE:

```
 <div id="h_menu">
        <div class='horizontal'>
            <ul>
                <li><a class='b' href='index.php' title='Home'><center>Home</center></a></li>
                <li><a href='include/a1.html' title='Testimonials'><center>Testimonials</center></a></li>
                <li><a href='include/a2.html' title='Prices'><center>Prices</center></a></li>
                <li><a href='include/a3.html' title='Galerry'><center>Galerry</center></a></li>
                <li><a href='include/a4.html' title='FAQs'><center>FAQ's</center></a></li>
                <li><a href='include/a5.html' title='Contacts'><center>Contacts</center></a></li>
            </ul>

        </div>

    </div>
```

CSS CODE of all of my menu links:

```
    #h_menu{
    width: 100%;
    height: 35px;
    background-color: #D8D8D8  ;
    margin:10px;
    margin-left: 0px;



}

.horizontal
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
}   

.horizontal ul
{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

}

.horizontal li 
{
    float: left;
}

.horizontal a
{
    display: block;
    width: 116px;

}

.horizontal a:link, .horizontal a:active
{
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
background-image:url(img/imgs/buttons1.png);
    font-size: 13px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-right: 1px;
    border-color: grey;
    border-right-style: solid;
    padding-top: 9px;
    height: 22px;
    width: 151px;
    color: #B00000;
    font-weight: bold;



}
.horizontal a:visited{


font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;

    font-size: 13px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-right: 1px;
    border-color: grey;
    border-right-style: solid;
    padding-top: 9px;
    height: 22px;
    width: 151px;
    color: #B00000;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.horizontal a:hover
{
        background-position: 0 -33px;
}
#h_menu .b 
{
         background-position: 0 -33px;
}
```

Comment: Not exactly clear what you are trying to ask.

Comment: I edited the question i hope now i explained it better. Sry if i was unclear.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use

```
background-color
```

instead of

```
color
```

in `.horizontal` `a:visited` class.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_sel_visited